# AWS step functions - reuse previous step's outputs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

in AWS step functions I know we can use `resultPath` to pass the current state's output to the next state along in its inputs. Say I have 3 states A, B, and C, when A finishes executing it passes its input and output to B as input, when B finishes, is there a way to pass B's output along with A's output + input to C as inputs? Please advise, thanks!

Comment: If ur states are lambdas, u would be able to send the appended result to the next state.

Answer (score 3):

if you only have a `resultPath` on your task then it appends the result to the incoming event *of that task* - So if Task A takes an Input of

```
{
    TaskAInput: Stuff
}
```

And has **only** a `resultPath: TaskAOutput` then the input for task B will be:

```
{
    TaskAInput: Stuff
    TaskAOutput: TaskAResult
}
```

That enters into Task B. If Task B **only** has a `resultPath: TaskBOutput` then

```
{
    TaskAInput: Stuff
    TaskAOutput: TaskAResult
    TaskBOutput: TaskBesult
}
```

and so on down the chain.

Note. If you attach an `outputPath` to any of the above steps it will output only that json path from the final combined input and results. If you use an inputPath at all it will cut down the input to just that going forward.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do the following:

**A function:**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ...
    result = ...
    return {
        "Ainput":event,
        "Aoutput": result
    }
```

**B function:**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ...
    result = ...
    return {
        "Ainput": event['Ainput'],
        "Aoutput": event['Aoutput'],
        "Boutput": result
    }
```

**C function:**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    Ainput = event['Ainput']
    Aoutput = event['Aoutput']
    Boutput = event['Boutput']
```

Now you can use that results on your C function as you want.

Comment: This is useful in certain situations, but is unecessary overhead in others where a `resultPath` will do the same. However, if you want new top level keys in the json and your lambda is returning a json object (ie a python dict) then this is definitely the way to go, as it gives you complete control over the input/output from any given lambda. You may however need to use a combination of `outputPath` and `resultPath` to prevent duplicate keys from the input ending up in the results. (set them to the same value)